# How does the CPU/Kernel allow user-space code to run when it's overwhelmed by Hardware Interrupts?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, cpu, interrupt

I have learned that when a Hardware Interrupt occurs, the CPU saves its registers to memory and immediately runs the corresponding code from an Interrupt Vector Table. Given that these HIs occur for pretty much every type of I/O operation and event, how can the CPU still be so performant that it handles all these HIs as well as allow user-space code to run? Or if it doesn't keep up with the processing of HIs, how does it allow user-space code to run from time to time?

Let's say you're playing an online shooter game where you constantly move your mouse, hold down multiple keys, receive and send packets thousands of times per second, update the screen for every single frame and load meshes from disk or write saves to the disk. That could potentially total up to tens of thousands, or maybe hundreds of thousands of HIs every second. And now for each HI, an instruction segment (lets say a few tens of lines of instructions) is supposed to run. That totals to potentially millions of code instructions to be run every single second - and that's without taking into consideration the time it takes to push the state of the CPU (registers, flags etc.) to memory and retrieving them from memory for each mode-switch...

And then on top of all that the CPU is supposed to run tens of thousands of lines of user-code to interpret all this data and calculate game mechanics, behavior, collisions, rendering etc. etc.

So how does the CPU / kernel ensure that user-space code gets to run as well? I can imagine that in a scenario I described above, user-space code would simply not get any time to run at all unless it had some sort of opposite hardware interrupt timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you literally did have so many hardware interrupts that another one was pending before processing the previous one finished, user-space code might only run 0 or maybe 1 instruction before being interrupted again.  So starvation would be possible if devices were raising interrupts faster than the CPU hardware+software could run the handlers.

I think [Intel CPUs finish the oldest instruction in the ROB (reorder buffer) before taking an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773814/unexpectedly-slow-performance-on-moving-from-register-to-frequently-accessed-var), so I think after an `iret` with another interrupt pending, user-space wouldn't totally starve on those CPUs.  Interrupts are nestable, though: a handler for one interrupt can be interrupted by a different interrupt.  So with multiple devices generating storms of interrupts, user-space could get *very* little CPU time.  (Different ISAs have different mechanisms for interrupt priority and blocking lower priority interrupts while servicing a higher-priority one, and for notifying the interrupt-controller that you're done handling this one so it can and should actually deliver again if the device is again or still asserting its interrupt-request signal.)

CPU speeds these days are in the GHz range, and able to run multiple instructions per cycle.  (But a modern x86 CPU stalls for maybe one to two hundred cycles between the last instruction in user-space and the first instruction in the interrupt handler, so it's not cheap.)

CPUs also have multiple cores, and each interrupt only needs to be handled by one core while the others are still working.  OSes may configure things so all interrupts from one device are handled by one core, all interrupts from another device by another core, so some of the relevant code and data might be hot in cache.  If I look `/proc/interrupts` on my Linux desktop, I can see there are actually 9 queues for my NVMe SSD, with each of q1-q8 having its interrupts handled by one of the 8 logical cores in my i7-6700k (4c8t, quad-core with hyperthreading).  And all the video card interrupts on one core, all the ethernet (e1000e driver) interrupts on another.  All the audio driver interrupts on another core (the hyperthread sibling of the core handling the video driver interrupts, perhaps just a coincidence.

Hundreds of thousands of interrupts per second would produce some slowdown.  Keyboard events are negligible; auto-repeat is done in software, not by the keyboard repeatedly sending press and release events.  It just sends an event for press and an event for release.  GPU drivers pass buffers of commands to the GPU for it to read.  Disks queue up DMA work, although there is an interrupt when a read completes.  (And maybe also a write.)  But a lot of file access is cached by the OS, only flushing to disk after a while. And read of a file that's already in RAM doesn't require any disk I/O.

Network cards are devices that could generate way too many interrupts, especially on servers (or workstations) with 10 Gbit or 100 Gbit ethernet, especially multiple such links.  The naive way for ethernet drivers to work is one interrupt per packet, and with typical non-jumbo frames only being about 1500 bytes, that's a *lot* of interrupts at those link speeds.  (Even 9k jumbo frames only help so much).

So modern network hardware and drivers in most OSes support polling or batching, only raising an interrupt every `n` packets, or after some timeout.  The driver gives the device a pointer into memory; the hardware writes incoming packet data to memory as they arrive so it doesn't need a lot of onboard RAM to buffer a batch of packets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/interrupt-moderation explains the Windows version of this, called Interrupt Moderation.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/networking/net_dim.html documents the Linux version: Dynamic Interrupt Moderation.  And the kernel API that network drivers can use to take advantage of the existing code, instead of individual drivers having to do it all themselves.

I'm not sure if any other devices (and drivers) like NVMe SSDs typically switch to polling (e.g. every millisecond, or every tens or hundreds of microseconds) under high activity.  That could be worse for I/O latency, but help throughput, so could be a good idea for workloads with a lot of I/O parallelism.

I think I've read that USB external hard drives typically *can't* reduce CPU load this way (and might involve more than one interrupt per sector because USB mass-storage is pretty primitive?), but ones that support USB-attached-SCSI (UASP) can be more efficient.  (Apparently that requires the motherboard vendor to pay royalties to license the ability to enable UASP, regardless of any actual hardware needed, if there is any.)  It might not be dynamic interrupt moderation, but command queueing and less CPU overhead for the same amount of data transferred does help transfer speed and CPU load. https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-3-uas-turbo,3215-4.html  / https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23741640

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a fast and detailed answer! I learned a lot. So basically, there are a a lot of optimizations to reduce the interrupt-count and CPUs are just so fast that it can handle tens of thousands of interrupts a second? It's truly amazing how fast CPUs are.